# How to remove gnome-games package without removing other packages?

Tags: debian, package-management

So I want to remove (more exactly `purge`) some packages like `gnome-games` from Debian 6. As already expected and know by research Aptitude also wants to remove in example the meta-package `gnome`, as without the `gnome-games` the `gnome` package is not fully installed. No problem with that. But now the difference comes: Aptitude also wants to remove a ton of other important packages! How can I just avoid that? I cannot understand what in example `network-manager` has to do with `gnome-games`. Unmarking `gnome-games` as manually installed does not make a difference.

However, this is my console dump:

```
root@testing:/home/branch# aptitude purge gnome-games
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
gnome-games{p} 
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 2,490 kB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome: Depends: gnome-games (>= 1:2.30) but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Remove the following packages:
1)     gnome                       

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be REMOVED:
aptdaemon{u} binfmt-support{u} cli-common{u} dnsmasq-base{u} epiphany-extensions{u}
evolution-exchange{u} gdebi{u} gdebi-core{u} gedit-plugins{u} gnome{a}
gnome-codec-install{u} gnome-games{p} gnome-office{u} gnome-themes-extras{u}
gnome-themes-more{u} gtk2-engines-smooth{u} libart2.0-cil{u} libgconf2.0-cil{u} 
libgee2{u} libgexiv2-0{u} libglade2.0-cil{u} libglib2.0-cil{u} libgmime2.4-cil{u} 
libgnome-vfs2.0-cil{u} libgnome2.24-cil{u} libgnomepanel2.24-cil{u} libgpod-common{u}
libgpod4{u} libgtk2.0-cil{u} libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil{u} libmono-addins0.2-cil{u}
libmono-cairo2.0-cil{u} libmono-corlib2.0-cil{u} libmono-i18n-west2.0-cil{u}
libmono-posix2.0-cil{u} libmono-security2.0-cil{u} libmono-sharpzip2.84-cil{u}
libmono-system2.0-cil{u} libmtp8{u} libndesk-dbus-glib1.0-cil{u} libndesk-dbus1.0-cil{u}
libnm-glib-vpn1{u} libpcsclite1{u} liferea{u} liferea-data{u} media-player-info{u}
mobile-broadband-provider-info{u} modemmanager{u} mono-2.0-gac{u} mono-gac{u}
mono-runtime{u} network-manager{u} network-manager-gnome{u} ppp{u} python-aptdaemon{u}
python-aptdaemon-gtk{u} python-mako{u} python-markupsafe{u} python-vte{u}
python-webkit{u} rhythmbox{u} rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder{u} rhythmbox-plugins{u}
shotwell{u} simple-scan{u} software-center{u} tcl{u} tcl8.4{u} tomboy{u} totem-mozilla{u}
transmission-common{u} transmission-gtk{u} update-manager-core{u} update-manager-gnome{u}
update-notifier{u} update-notifier-common{u} usb-modeswitch{u} usb-modeswitch-data{u}
wpasupplicant{u}
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 79 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 143 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
Abort.
```

**Edit**: Aptitude wants to remove all the packages as it assumes they are unused after removing the `gnome` metapackage. But that definitely is not the case. How to tell aptitude that it simply keeps those packages? It does not give any other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that all of those were automatically installed as dependencies of the `gnome` metapackage.  As you said, the gnome metapackage is incomplete without the gnome-games package, so it must be removed.  That renders all the packages listed unused and so `aptitude` wants to remove them. There may be a way to remove gnome without removing its unused dependencies, but a quick search didn't show one and I suspect that it would try to uninstall them every time you removed something else.  Your best bet is probably to figure out which of those packages you explicitly want and mark them manually installed, then let it uninstall the remainder if they're still unneeded.

Comment: is right, what you could try is using **`aptitude`'s GUI** to *remove `gnome`* and, in the preview (after *one* `g`), **deselect the parts you want to keep** from the list of packages-to-be-removed (i.e. remove the `A` from `ipA` by pressing `M`).  You can always press `Ctrl+t` and select something like *Forget planned actions* when you got stuck or decide to start over.

Comment: Thank you both for the hints. Now I solved the matter in the way, that I did some _copy-pasta_. I simply copied the long list of packages aptitude wanted to remove and marked those as manually installed. Then I purged the `gnome-games` package and only the `gnome` metapackage has been removed. Though I do not think that this is the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: That last key is meant to be `m`, not `M`; see also [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5200/11539). (*edit* ok, fine.)

Answer (score 9):

For Debian and spinoffs, after you login to Gnome hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and get to a console window.

Login as root OR yourself then `sudo su` (different distros get stupid about root, sudo and su).

Type `apt-get remove gnome-games` without quotes and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>- it will say its getting rid of gnome and gnome-games - choose `Yes` or `OK` - it will mark them all for removal.

Then type `apt-get install gnome-core` and choose `Yes` to install it will mark gnome-core to stay and show you all the game apps that are no longer in use and can be auto removed.

Then type `apt-get autoremove` and you should see all the game data about to be blasted out and your ready to go - no baloney, no removing entire gnome etc.

`apt-get clean` or `apt-get autoclean` can get you some disk space from cached install files.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: This is the right answer!

Comment: This works for me as well. Thank :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, so created a list of games I uninstalled and created a [readme file](https://github.com/yandiro/remove-gnome-games/blob/main/README.md) on this repository, [yandiro](https://github.com/yandiro)/[remove-gnome-games](https://github.com/yandiro/remove-gnome-games-gnome-games).

Just copy and paste:

```
sudo apt purge iagno lightsoff four-in-a-row gnome-robots pegsolitaire gnome-2048 hitori gnome-klotski gnome-mines gnome-mahjongg gnome-sudoku quadrapassel swell-foop gnome-tetravex gnome-taquin aisleriot && sudo apt autoremove
```

Maybe this helps.

Comment: [Edit] and paste the command into your answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/393842)

Answer (score 0):

By default, aptitude looks for and uninstalls dependencies, which is USUALLY exactly what you want to do.  The comprehensive gnome-games package apparently has various games that include these diverse dependencies.

HOWEVER, the dpkg -r command does NOT look for dependencies; it just removes precisely what you tell it to.  In many cases that would be a bad thing (as it could potentially leave your system unstable), but in this instance, instability would be unlikely and it may be the best solution.